# How to insert values to AzureSQL database using Azure functions

Tags: java, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I am fetching the values from an API and returning it.
Those values should be Inserted into database using AZURE FUNCTIONS.

```
    @FunctionName("HttpTrigger-Java")
    public JSONObject run(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { 
    HttpMethod.GET,
    HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION) 
    HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
    final ExecutionContext context) throws ParseException, IOException {
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

    String bearerToken="Bearer "+ token; 
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); 
    HttpGet requests=new HttpGet("/2.0/clusters/list");//GET the LIST
    requests.addHeader("Authorization",bearerToken); //Adding the bearer token
    requests.addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache"); 
    HttpResponse response=client.execute(requests); 
    System.out.println("Response Code:" + 
    response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    System.out.println("Gather clusters details\n"); 
    JSONObject cluster = new JSONObject(json); 
    JSONArray Jarray=cluster.getJSONArray("clusters");
    for (int i=0;i< Jarray.length();i++)
    {
    JSONObject clusters = Jarray.getJSONObject(i); 
    String cluster_id=clusters.get("cluster_id").toString(); 
    String cluster_name=clusters.get("cluster_name").toString();
    String start_timestamp=clusters.get("start_time").toString(); 
    System.out.println("ClusterId:"+cluster_id+"\t"+"ClusterName:"
    +cluster_name+"\t"+"start_time:"+start_timestamp+"\n");
    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=200) {
    System.out.println("Failed HTTP response"+response.getStatusLine().
    getStatusCode()+" "+Jarray);
    }
    }
    return cluster;
    }

Code to insert into DATABASE

    public void insertdb(JSONObject ResJ) throws Exception{
    Connection con = ConnectToDB(); 
    String tablename="cluster_info";
    JSONArray array=ResJ.getJSONArray("clusters");
    for (int j=0;j< array.length();j++)
    {
    JSONObject clusters = array.getJSONObject(j); 
    String cluster_id=clusters.get("cluster_id").toString();
    String cluster_name=clusters.get("cluster_name").toString();
    String start_timestamp=clusters.get("start_time").toString();
    String terminated_timestamp=clusters.get("terminated_time").toString(); 
    String sql =" INSERT INTO " + tablename + " 
    (cluster_id,cluster_name,start_timestamp,terminated_timestamp) VALUES 
    (?,?,?,?)"; 
    PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1, cluster_id); 
    pstmt.setString(2, cluster_name); 
    pstmt.setString(3, start_timestamp); 
    pstmt.setString(4, terminated_timestamp); 
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }     
    return ;
    }
```

How can I push the result of the list into SQL database? Should it contain a main method? If so, how do I call these two method in Azure functions?

I am new to Azure functions. Normal Java code is working fine.

Comment: Hey, I may be missing something. So did you combine both in the same function and it did not work? 
This is will not work public JSONObject run.
Hers is some examples,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/blob/dev/endtoendtests/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/functions/endtoend/HttpTriggerTests.java

Comment: Is that you use one method as one Azure function ?

Comment: @JimXu No In one Azure function I need Two different methods.

One method to fetch the details.
Second method to Insert Those values fetched from the first method.

Comment: Is that you want to know if you can call the two methods in one Azure function? Besides, is that you use Azure function to fetch details and the second method need these details?

Comment: @JimXu Yes I want to know how to call those methods in a single function.
Yes First method to fetch details and second method to Insert those details fetched.

Comment: Ok. I see. I will do some research.

Comment: According to my test, we can directly call other methods which are defined by ourselves in Azure function trigger.